# Copying files between users Using Telnet

Tags: file-copy, telnet

How to copy a file from home directory `User A` to home directory of `User B` using `telnet`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422148/is-there-a-way-to-copy-a-file-over-telnet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610834/transfer-files-over-telnet

Comment: Telnet from where to where? Which operating systems?

Comment: Except for communication with really low-end devices, please banish telnet servers from your network. Use ssh. And if you're just using telnet as a tool to transfer data, not for logins, see netcat—unlike telnet, it defaults to binary clean.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a strict requirement, that you have to use telnet to accomplish the task? If not, please consider using an ssh connection to the server.

```
ssh username@domain.com

At command line after giving a password:
cp /home/of/user/A/fileX /home/of/user/B
```

These commands would do the trick in that case.